# xpath expression to get value of attribute x where value of attribute y equals z

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have an XML file containing data looking as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document date="2021-03-01" name="dataExport">

<CASHFLOW CASHFLOW_ID="001" C001="06-08"/><CASHFLOW_FIELD CASHFLOW_ID="001" C001="06-08" FIELDNAME="A001" VALUE="0"/><CASHFLOW_FIELD CASHFLOW_ID="001" F001="04-08-01" FIELDNAME="C254" VALUE="15.78"/>

<CASHFLOW CASHFLOW_ID="002" C001="06-08"/><CASHFLOW_FIELD CASHFLOW_ID="001" C001="06-08" FIELDNAME="A001" VALUE="2"/><CASHFLOW_FIELD CASHFLOW_ID="002" C001="06-08" FIELDNAME="C254" VALUE="10.55"/>

</document>
```

Using XPath, I want to get the value of attribute "VALUE" where attribute "CASHFLOW_ID" has value "002" and attribute "FIELDNAME" has value "C254". That is, I want to have value **"10.55"**.

I tried the following to achieve my goal (using python library lxml):

```
value_I_want = tree.xpath("//@VALUE[@CASHFLOW_ID='001'][@FIELDNAME='C254']")
```

But instead of giving me `10.55`, this gives me an empty list (`[]`).

I also tried the following:

```
value_I_want = tree.xpath("//[@VALUE][@CASHFLOW_ID='001'][@FIELDNAME='C254']")
```

... But this is an invalid expression.

What's the correct XPath expression to get what I want?

Comment: Posted XML is not well formed since there is no root which may contain namespaces affecting parsing. Please post actual, fuller, sample XML and not line snippets. Also, post all `import` lines of Python. Standard library `etree` does not support `xpath`. Ultimately, we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Correct syntax](https://videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3CCASHFLOW%20CASHFLOW_ID%3D%22001%22%20C001%3D%2206-08%22%2F%3E%3CCASHFLOW_FIELD%20CASHFLOW_ID%3D%22001%22%20C001%3D%2206-08%22%20FIELDNAME%3D%22A001%22%20VALUE%3D%220%22%2F%3E%3CCASHFLOW_FIELD%20CASHFLOW_ID%3D%22001%22%20F001%3D%2204-08-01%22%20FIELDNAME%3D%22C254%22%20VALUE%3D%2215.78%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%3CCASHFLOW%20CASHFLOW_ID%3D%22002%22%20C001%3D%2206-08%22%2F%3E%3CCASHFLOW_FIELD%20CASHFLOW_ID%3D%22001%22%20C001%3D%2206-08%22%20FIELDNAME%3D%22A001%22%20VALUE%3D%222%22%2F%3E%3CCASHFLOW_FIELD%20CASHFLOW_ID%3D%22002%22%20C001%3D%2206-08%22%20FIELDNAME%3D%22C254%22%20VALUE%3D%2210.55%22%2F%3E&=&extract=%2F%2FCASHFLOW_FIELD%5B%40CASHFLOW_ID%3D%27001%27%20and%20%40FIELDNAME%3D%27C254%27%5D%2F%40VALUE&=%20%2F%2FCASHFLOW_FIELD%5B%40CASHFLOW_ID%3D%27001%27%20and%20%40FIELDNAME%3D%27C254%27%5D%2F%40VALUE&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto) would be

```
//CASHFLOW_FIELD[@CASHFLOW_ID='001' and @FIELDNAME='C254']/@VALUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your solution still returns an empty list.

Comment: @Thomas_SO are you sure that provided XML sample is the same as real XML?

Comment: thank you for the hint. Your solution is correct. It just didn't work in my case because my query is inside a loop and instead of searching for @CASHFLOW_ID='001' I am actually searching for @CASHFLOW_ID=cashflow_id. I will create a new question for this other problem.

Comment: Hallo @JaSON, I created a new question for the other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748679/xpath-expression-works-with-literal-but-not-with-variable